# How to remove item from an anonymous list

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, anonymous-function

Work on EF 4 C#.I have one anonymous list .Want to remove item from anonymous list

```
    Anonymous list :

    var temp=from p in contex.students select p;//it’s a complex query,for now just use simple select

    foreach(var item in temp)
    {
     if(item.StudentID)//if satisfy some condition then want to remove this student information from      anonymous list
    {
         temp=temp.where(p=>studentID!=item.studentID);
    }
    }
```

Above syntax is not working for me.I just want to remove item base on several condition .Need help how to remove item from anonymous list.

If have any query plz ask.thanks in advanced.

Comment: ... what is studentID? the condition in the Where doesn't use the variable p at all... plus in the foreach you are missing a "in"

Comment: When posting code, please post some valid C# code.

Comment: looks like `pseudo code`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not be removing items from the list as you go, because doing so invalidates the iterator of the `foreach` loop. You can do what you want without a loop:

```
var temp = contex.students.Where(item => !CheckCondition(item.StudentID));
```

Recall that `Where` lets you operate on the entire collection as a whole. The `CheckCondition` would be called on every student ID (I tried to follow your example; you do not need to base the selection solely on the `StudentID`), and all students who pass `CheckCondition` would be removed.

Note that if `contex` is an EF/LINQ2SQL context, you would need to add `AsEnumerable()` before checking conditions using your C# code:

```
var temp = contex.students
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Where(item => !CheckCondition(item.StudentID));
```